# Do I always need to use ajax to post jquery variables or value to controller?

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter, controller

I'm curious do I always need to use ajax to post simple value or variable to controller.

**Like for example I have a jquery of:**

```
var exampleId = document.getElementById("sampleId").value;

$.ajax({
            url:  'link/controller' + $exampleId,
            type: 'post'

}); // ajax
```

or there's a simple way to pass it to a controller without using ajax.

Comment: You can include the value as a query string parameter in any link or page request, or include it in a form post.

Comment: if you want to go to the second page then pass those value with `POST` or `GET` form request. But if you want that page din't change and you get the data from controller function back to the same page. you have to use ajax always

Comment: Oh thanks for the answer :)

Comment: @AlivetoDie one can direct that GET/POST to an iframe (which does not have to be visible) and avoid navigation